# Problem has only fixed variables-ifopt

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to ifopt. I get "Problem has only fixed variables" although I am trying to add only very small changes to test_vars_constr_cost.h to solve a new optimization problem.
Could you help me?

Thank you,
Barbara

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358416/problem-has-only-fixed-variables-ifopt/) by [barbara](https://answers.ros.org/users/57202/barbara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2020-07-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-01**:
Please note: IFOPT is not ROS-related, nor maintained as part of ROS.

You'l want to find a better venue for posting these sorts of support requests.

**Comment by [Alexander Winkler](https://answers.ros.org/users/33039/alexander-winkler/) on 2020-08-02**:
It is. There are ROS binaries: sudo apt install ros-melodic-ifopt.

http://wiki.ros.org/ifopt

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-03**:
Yes, I know.

But ROS Kinetic also packages and ships with OpenCV 3 (versus v2 on the platforms it's supported on), but we still don't answer OpenCV questions here on ROS Answers.

A library which has been released through the ROS buildfarm does not make it "part of ROS" necessarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Got it. I am not passing the bounds on the variables in GetBounds() correctly.

---

Originally posted by [barbara](https://answers.ros.org/users/57202/barbara/) with karma: 26 on 2020-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1